# Binding event not firing on Adapter

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-databinding, android-architecture-components

I am following Android Archt. [component](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) to build a project. Following the guidelines I have created a custom Adapter named CataloguesAdapter extending DataBoundListAdapter as :

```
public class CataloguesAdapter extends DataBoundListAdapter<CatalogueEntity, CatalogueItemBinding> {

    private final android.databinding.DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent;
    private final ContributorClickCallback callback;
    private CatalogueItemBinding mBinding;

    public CataloguesAdapter(DataBindingComponent dataBindingComponent,
                             ContributorClickCallback callback) {
        this.dataBindingComponent = dataBindingComponent;
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected CatalogueItemBinding createBinding(ViewGroup parent) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        R.layout.catalogue_item, parent, false,
                        dataBindingComponent);

       //while this click event is working fine
        mBinding.getRoot().setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CatalogueEntity catalogueEntity = mBinding.getCatalogue();
            if (catalogueEntity != null && callback != null) {
                callback.onClick(catalogueEntity);
            }
        });

        //todo:not working, this event is not firing
        mBinding.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(v-> callback.onItemDelete());

        return mBinding;
    }
}
```

I am implementing swipe to delete layout on Recycler view item. Below is the XML layout of list item:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <variable
            name="catalogue"
            type="com.mindtree.igxbridge.traderapp.datasource.local.entity.CatalogueEntity" />

    </data>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_background"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/colorRed">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/delete_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_30_dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30_dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10_dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_delete"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10_dp"
                    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/delete_icon"
                    android:text="@string/text_delete"
                    android:textColor="@color/Material.87.white"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/view_foreground"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
                    android:id="@+id/arrow_icon"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/dimen_30_dp"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/dimen_30_dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/dimen_10_dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_right" />               

            </RelativeLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</layout>
```

Another operation like swipe left/right is working fine but clicking on Delete button event is not getting called.

I tried checking findViewbyId and register click event by that, but no luck with that too. 
While CatalogueItemBinding is registered correctly, I am not able to find any other source of error.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I have misunderstood your code. You used a **FrameLayout** to host two relative layouts one top of each other (foreground and background). The delete button is in the background and foreground has *match_parent* in its width attribute. Therefore, I think the delete button is getting covered by the foreground, leading to "not firing of the event".

**Possible Solution**

Try incorporating the delete button in the foreground. It makes sense to put UI components in the front.

Comment: I have implemented swipe to delete. While swiping view_background comes up and delete button shows up. So I should have able to click on delete button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to tell your adapter class to where your XML is set or not to adapter class. just create a variable in XML which will import your adapter class have look.

```
 <variable
     name="myAdapter" 
     type="import your adapter class">
 </variable>
```

Now set this variable to your adapter.

```
 @Override
    protected CatalogueItemBinding createBinding(ViewGroup parent) {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil
                .inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                        R.layout.catalogue_item, parent, false,
                        dataBindingComponent);
        mBinding .setmyAdapter(this);      
        return mBinding;
    }
}
```

then your click will work. Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hey Hemant, I tried all three options :  mBinding.setAdapter(this);
        mBinding.setVariable(R.layout.catalogue_item, this);
        mBinding.executePendingBindings();   It didn't worked, any other suggestion.

Comment: after set adapter you have to call click listener event where you want to call delete function.

Comment: yes I am doing it this way: //todo:not working
        mBinding.deleteIcon.setOnClickListener(v-> callback.onItemDelete()); and callback is also implemented appropriately.